# Can't access users in console while using Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I am making a Rails app that uses the Rolify gem with Devise and CanCan.

Running the rolify generators like this

```
rails g rolify:role
```

put the rolify method at the top of the Users model like so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
```

In addition to creating the Role.rb model.

```
   class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
     belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

     scopify

   end
```

I haven't done anything else with rolify yet. When I try to load the Users in rails console, however, I get the following error.

```
>> User.all
NameError: undefined local variable or method `rolify' for #<Class:0x007f813d32ce48>
```

I'm using `Rails 3.2.12`

Ruby Version

```
    ruby -v
    ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

I assume this is not expected behavior. Can anyone suggest a solution. It would not be worth it for me to use rolify if I can't access the User model in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomoko, try adding `extend Rolify` before rolify, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Rolify
  rolify
end
```